# change IPython magic function prefix (from '%' to ':'), Anyway to?

Tags: ipython

Is there any way to change IPython magic function prefix from default '%' ? I can't found any option in ipython_config.py

Since I am using vim and ghci, I (somehow) trained myself to think for ':' as command prefix already.

This very annoying when I want to call magic function and automatic prefixing ':' to every IPython magic function call , e.g, :cd, :ed and :load

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magic escape is hard-coded in a lot of places,
but if all you want to do is minimize the penalty of your vim-inflicted muscle memory,
you can tell the inputsplitter to treat your colons as percents:

```
import re
from IPython.core import splitinput
from IPython.core.inputsplitter import transform_escaped

# this is a one-character change, adding colon to the second group,
# so the line splitter will interpret ':' as an escape char
splitinput.line_split = line_split = re.compile("""
             ^(\s*)               # any leading space
             ([,;/%:]|!!?|\?\??)?  # escape character or characters
             \s*(%{0,2}[\w\.\*]*)     # function/method, possibly with leading %
                                  # to correctly treat things like '?%magic'
             (.*?$|$)             # rest of line
             """, re.VERBOSE)

# treat colon the same as percent:
transform_escaped.tr[':'] = transform_escaped._tr_magic
```

Now, you should be able to do things like:

```
:cd foo

for t in range(3):
    :time time.sleep(t)
```

If you want this to always fire, you can put this code in an IPython startup file (~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/whatever.py).

These are not exactly public APIs, so I wouldn't trust them to not mess anything up, but it seems to work in current master.

Comment: Thanks, your solution work! (at least for now, I better train myself using default _%_ as a longterm solution)

I can't believe IPython developers doesn't use vim and decide to **hardcode** things.

Also I just curious where _%_ came from?

Comment: It had to be something that wasn't valid syntax, and `%` was just picked.  IPython was the first real Python project for a number of the original contributors.  It was done many years ago, and just hasn't changed as there was no reason to (personally, I don't like ':').  IPython has been in the process of substantial cleanup, and that should result in being able to make changes like this more straightforward. The process is not yet complete, though.

Comment: Any news on the cleanup work?  Many consoles has their magic variables and functions and they may defer in the prefix characters ($, :, %, >, ?, etc.). So really making things configurable is the best choice. And I think it's not too hard to do.